# How to set an intent on a linkify'd textview

Tags: java, android, twitter, hashtag, linkify

I need help with creating hashtags. I've been able to linkify when I hashtag in my textview,that works fine. I just need to be able to push that hashtag into another activity as a string extra. How can I implement a feature like this? Here is my code.

```
Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.compile("[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\b");

String newActivityURL = "INSERT ACTIVITY";

Linkify.addLinks(mViewHolder.tvDesc, tagMatcher, newActivityURL);
```